# Is there supposed to be feedback on edit-review audits?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, review-audits

I think I passed an edit-review audit today. I rejected something that was so horrible I was sure it was a honeypot. But nothing happened. I checked in the history and yes, it was an audit. I can't find it now, to link to it, but I found [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1431707#./1431707?&_suid=135967403116101687690484355971) that I didn't even notice at the time. The one that I went back and looked at had a more memorable edit-comment than the one I've linked to.

So, if you pass the audit there is no "congratulations" as there is with the other audits. Should there be? What happens if you fail?

Comment: Related: You can hit your browser's "Back" button to go back and view the results of your review. I do this when I suspect that a review was an audit and no 'success' notification comes up.

Answer (score 12):

We now give feedback after *all* audits, pass or fail.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! Also, you probably want to mark the [corresponding feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170528/add-a-positive-feedback-for-all-types-of-review-audits?noredirect=1#comment505505_170528) as status-completed. :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If you fail, you get a message along the lines of "This was an audit and you FAILED, please read carefully next time.".
In my case, I was trying to [edit something that needed improving anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1412179) even before the spam, but looking back, was fairly minor, and should have been rejected then editied seperately.

The review process also doesn't give positive feedback for other normal reviews, it only warns when there is a problem.

Comment: no, I have seen "congratulations this was only a test" on other reviews. Are you saying you saw the FAILED message when clicking Improve on a suggested edit?

Comment: @KateGregory Yes, it told me I should have rejected it instead. I can't remember the exact text though.

Comment: I believe the honeypots are supposed to be posts that don't need any editing and are then vandalized with random stuff. They would have to be very confident that Improve would never be right. You might want to include a link to that one so the honeypot-making process can be refined

Comment: @KateGregory [Done](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1412179). Looking back, I probably should have rejected it :)

Comment: Yeah, in general just reject edits that do *absolutely nothing good* to the original post, even if the post itself does need some work. You can always open it up separately to edit, but rejecting out of hand ensures that, should something happen, the bad edit isn't sitting around blocking good ones from being made.

Comment: ^ That explains the rejection of my perfectly good tag addition to a question without notification. Instead of it being rejected for the tags it was rejected (by two people) for not improving the question (which was untouched).

Comment: @Shog9, I see that there are now explicit "approve and edit" and "reject and edit" buttons.