# Suggested Edit audits don't out themselves as audits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, review-audits, review-abuse

Whenever you pass a [review audit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152709) of the five posts queues, you get one of that heart-warming messages, telling you how awesome you are for actually paying attention and not just clicking <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd>, <kbd>Leave Open</kbd> or <kbd>Leave Closed</kbd> just to increase your review count.

Being even more awesome for not clicking blindly approve when reviewing suggested edits, I'd expect the same for the new [honeypot suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165489).

However, that's not the case. After clicking <kbd>Reject</kbd> ⟶ **Vandalism** ⟶ <kbd>Reject</kbd>, the next suggested edit gets loaded as usual, leaving me without any notification whatsoever that the suggested edit I just reviewed was a fake one.

To make matters worse, these edit are apparently suggested by users that propose other (valid) edits and would (hopefully) never vandalize a post in such a manner.<sup>1</sup>

The first time I reviewed a honeypot edit, I went through the recent suggested edits of that user, only to find that the user hadn't attempted to vandalize any post before that occasion. I did that *before* rejecting the suggested edit, so I still had no idea what was going on. I came close to flagging the user claiming in a custom message that he was probably drunk, but refrained from it giving him the benefit of the doubt.<sup>2</sup>

Now, a couple of minutes ago, I found another edit just like the first one. I initially thought it was from the same user, but digging through my review history, I found out that it was from somebody else. When I finally found it, I knew at last what had been going on: Instead of **Rejected**, the review said **Review audit passed**.

This needs fixing. While I'm not comfortable at all with the fact that those honeypot edits are attributed to actual users, I guess it's necessary to prevent users from reviewing an edit based solely on *who* proposed it. But we need *at least* the "It was all a joke!" message after completing the review task.

---

<sup>1</sup> All other review queues contain posts that were actually posted by those users. *Those* posts do not necessarily need an indicator that you just got audited.

<sup>2</sup> More than once, I have brushed over the touchpad of my laptop with my palm, which made me type in another line or even another window. And that was sober!

Comment: Immediately after posting my question, I found [Is there supposed to be feedback on edit-review audits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165924). Well, this is a feature request, so it may not be a duplicate.

Comment: I like my warm fuzzy feelings... gimme audit-success feedback! As a side note, the suggested edit honeypots are hilarious.