# Looking back at suggested-edit review audits throws a 500 error message

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, review-audits, 500-server-error

I was browsing MSE about review audits, etc., and came upon [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165924/is-there-supposed-to-be-feedback-on-edit-review-audits) question. It had a link to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1431707) suggested edit review audit, but instead of showing "Review audit completed at {date}" or "failed", it simply shows an error message (HTTP status code 500 from the console):

[image: screenshot of the error occurring]

I'm also sure I chanced upon one on Ask Ubuntu some time ago. Can we fix that?

Comment: I had this too yesterday. I tried to track it down, followed the trail which dead-ended in a link to an "orphan wiki" - which was blank. I've no clue what that meant at all. It's [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/207592/revisions).

Comment: Ah, found the [edit history](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/79788).

Comment: also reported on MSO (just to link the two): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409250/11407695

Comment: [tag:status-completed]  It works now.

Comment: Should it not be marked as such and not closed as "no repro", folks? Because it is not like it never happened

Comment: @OlegValter The closure reason literally says *"* ***Changes to the system*** or to the circumstances affecting the asker ***have rendered it obsolete.*** *"* - I fail to see how it's not correct.

Comment: @Nick well... should we ditch the [meta-tag:status-completed] then? Because by definition a bug fixed is a bug that is no longer reproducible

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] isn't just for bug reports though?

Comment: May I inquire what are [these 7300 questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bstatus-completed%5d%20%5bbug%5d%20closed%3ano) about then? :)

Comment: @OlegValter Well if you can give a valid reason for why the closure reason is _wrong_ and not just different I might agree

Comment: @Nick sure, but I won't ever be as eloquent about it as [this Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/339370/786798) on "When to close a bug report as no longer reproducible?"

Comment: Perhaps you could decide, @Glorfindel?  Reopen and tag appropriately, or leave it how it is? (I'm ambivalent in this case, BTW)

Comment: @OlegValter No need to be eloquent, just see this bit: "*The close reason is for cases where it might have been solved accidentally, and is actually closer to [status-norepro]*" So yeah, reopening is fine with me.  This was very likely *not* an accident.

Comment: @Ollie yeah, I am always for having an official response from staff rather than a closure - without it, who knows whether it is dormant in the source code and will bite at the worst possible time? Having a staff answer (if they ever find it, though) at least leaves a paper trail